# Can I count the number of pokes with the Facebook API? me/pokes returns only one poke

Tags: javascript, facebook

I found this resource: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fpokes, but that only displays one poke. Can I get more pokes? I've also found this older question; [Facebook FQL / Graph - Get all current pokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505417/facebook-fql-graph-get-all-current-pokes), which helped, but doesn't show the number of pokes ether.

I want to show how often user x has poked user y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is maximally one poke available. And if you poke back/delete poke, it is deleted from your profile (from API, too)

SO you have no chance to see how often user x has poked user y

Answer (score 0):

Could you not store each individual poke externally and register them as individual values and count them that way. I am not an expert at coding but that may work...

Comment: Only from the moment you start to monitor, and you'd need to ping. There's no way to see past pokes. This question has become very old tho, it's not at all relevant to me anymore, maybe you should try answering newer questions.