# Is there a way to poke via the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to poke another user via the Graph API? Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505417/facebook-fql-graph-get-all-current-pokes), and using the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), I'm POSTing to "/USERID/pokes", I've granted it (both the Graph API app, and my app) all extended permissions, but I'm still getting:

```
"error": {
   "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
   "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

The previously mentioned post states the app needs to be whitelisted, but that appears to be a different message; for example, if I try to post to my inbox, I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

So:

1. Is it possible to send a poke via the Graph API?
2. If it is possible, and my app does need to be whitelisted, where do I request it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API exists, but it's whitelisted to Official FB Apps only for now. There's no timeline on when it will be available generally.

Comment: Thanks Colm; it's not the answer I was hoping for, but at least I can stop combing through obscure search results. :-)

Comment: `answered Nov 10 2011` - Is this answer still up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

They do whitelist that api to more than just official FB apps.  For example, Friendly and MyPad ipad apps have poke functionality and are not official FB apps. You just have to know the right person to talk to.  For a good list of people to start talking to, the Facebook Developer Group has a [list of employees](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/doc/254151647961690/) you could try to reach out to.

Comment: "The doc has been deleted." Unfortunately there are a lot of points of access that Facebook Preferred Developers have access to that everyone else doesn't. https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/